# Check if 2 URLs are equal

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a method that tests if 2 URLs are equal, ie point to the same place?
I am not talking about 2 URLs with different domain names pointing to the same IP address but for example, 2 URLs that point to the same .aspx page:

- http://example.com/Products/Default.aspx?A=B&C=D&E=F

is equal to these:

- http://example.com/Products/Default.aspx
- http://example.com/Products/
- `~/Products/Default.aspx`
- `~/Products/`

Note/assumtions

1. QueryString Values are Ignored
2. ASP.NET (Pref C#)
3. Default.aspx is the default page

**----UPDATE----**

This is a very crude method that tests a URL to see if matches the current URL:
I tried creating a `new Uri()` with both the local and check URLs but dont know that works and went down the string checking avenue.
The implementation of the SiteMapProvider skips this step if the URL starts with "HTTP" as this assumes an external URL. Since I have a SaaS framework that will always ensure relative paths (as these can be on different subdomains) it easier to strip things down.

Any comments on optimization? I guess for a start we can pass in a variable containing the current URL? Not sure of the overhead of calling `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath` many times?

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Assumes URL is relative aspx page or folder path
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool CurrentURLMatch(string url)
{
    string localURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath;
    
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host == "localhost")
    {
        localURL = localURL.Substring(localURL.IndexOf('/') + 1);
        localURL = localURL.Substring(localURL.IndexOf('/'));
    }
    string compareURL = url.ToLower();

    // Remove QueryString Values
    if (localURL.Contains("?"))
    {
        localURL = localURL.Split('?')[0];
    }

    if (compareURL.Contains("?"))
    {
        compareURL = compareURL.Split('?')[0];
    }

    if (localURL.Contains("#"))
    {
        localURL = localURL.Split('#')[0];
    }
    if (compareURL.Contains("?"))
    {
        compareURL = compareURL.Split('#')[0];
    }

    // Prepare End of Local URL
    if (!localURL.Contains("aspx"))
    {
        if (!localURL.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            localURL = String.Concat(localURL, "/");
        }
    }

    // Prepare End of Compare URL
    if (!compareURL.Contains("aspx"))
    {
        if (!compareURL.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            compareURL = String.Concat(localURL, "/");
        }
    }

    if (localURL.EndsWith(@"/"))
    {
        localURL = String.Concat(localURL, "Default.aspx");
    }

    if (compareURL.EndsWith(@"/"))
    {
        compareURL = String.Concat(compareURL, "Default.aspx");
    }

    if (compareURL.Contains(@"//"))
    {
        compareURL = compareURL.Replace(@"//", String.Empty);
        compareURL = compareURL.Substring(compareURL.IndexOf("/") + 1);
    }

    compareURL = compareURL.Replace("~", String.Empty);

    if (localURL == compareURL)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please note, the above code is not fully tested and requires optimization. I will updated it through testing. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: @Mark: It'd probably be quite a bit easier to use the `Uri` class, though. All you'd have to string-wise is replace `~` with the current base URL, then create `Uri` objects from the URLs and just do an equivalency comparison. That would eliminate a lot of the code you have in your solution.

Comment: (Basically, the `Uri` class does most if not all of those normalization techniques for you.)

Comment: Ok thanks Cat, I will have a look into that. I was trying to use the LocalPath and RelativeURI kind on the basis that they were all closer to relative paths than absolute. Thanks

Comment: I have tried both a String Manipulation method, similar to the above and using Uri Matching however, its seems that the string method has prevailed in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be looking for [URL normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) techniques. They might be a good starting point :)

Once you have normalized the URLs, you simply need to check if they are equal (keep in mind your assumptions, for instance, you discard the querystring).

Comment: I have gone down this route, looking at the link you provided and as you say, with the requirements it does make it slightly easier to reduce the URL down to something I can compare. I think an optimized string based comparison is the most efficient solution in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

for the record, here is the translation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL%5Fnormalization to C#:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace UrlNormalizationTest
{
    public static class UrlNormalization
    {
        public static bool AreTheSameUrls(this string url1, string url2)
        {
            url1 = url1.NormalizeUrl();
            url2 = url2.NormalizeUrl();
            return url1.Equals(url2);
        }

        public static bool AreTheSameUrls(this Uri uri1, Uri uri2)
        {
            var url1 = uri1.NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = uri2.NormalizeUrl();
            return url1.Equals(url2);
        }

        public static string[] DefaultDirectoryIndexes = new[]
            {
                "default.asp",
                "default.aspx",
                "index.htm",
                "index.html",
                "index.php"
            };

        public static string NormalizeUrl(this Uri uri)
        {
            var url = urlToLower(uri);
            url = limitProtocols(url);
            url = removeDefaultDirectoryIndexes(url);
            url = removeTheFragment(url);
            url = removeDuplicateSlashes(url);
            url = addWww(url);
            url = removeFeedburnerPart(url);
            return removeTrailingSlashAndEmptyQuery(url);
        }

        public static string NormalizeUrl(this string url)
        {
            return NormalizeUrl(new Uri(url));
        }

        private static string removeFeedburnerPart(string url)
        {
            var idx = url.IndexOf("utm_source=", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            return idx == -1 ? url : url.Substring(0, idx - 1);
        }

        private static string addWww(string url)
        {
            if (new Uri(url).Host.Split('.').Length == 2 && !url.Contains("://www."))
            {
               return url.Replace("://", "://www.");
            }
            return url;
        }

        private static string removeDuplicateSlashes(string url)
        {
            var path = new Uri(url).AbsolutePath;
            return path.Contains("//") ? url.Replace(path, path.Replace("//", "/")) : url;
        }

        private static string limitProtocols(string url)
        {
            return new Uri(url).Scheme == "https" ? url.Replace("https://", "http://") : url;
        }

        private static string removeTheFragment(string url)
        {
            var fragment = new Uri(url).Fragment;
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fragment) ? url : url.Replace(fragment, string.Empty);
        }

        private static string urlToLower(Uri uri)
        {
            return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.AbsoluteUri.ToLowerInvariant());
        }

        private static string removeTrailingSlashAndEmptyQuery(string url)
        {
            return url
                    .TrimEnd(new[] { '?' })
                    .TrimEnd(new[] { '/' });
        }

        private static string removeDefaultDirectoryIndexes(string url)
        {
            foreach (var index in DefaultDirectoryIndexes)
            {
                if (url.EndsWith(index))
                {
                    url = url.TrimEnd(index.ToCharArray());
                    break;
                }
            }
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

With the following tests:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using UrlNormalizationTest;

namespace UrlNormalization.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1ConvertingTheSchemeAndHostToLowercase()
        {
            var url1 = "HTTP://www.Example.com/".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test2CapitalizingLettersInEscapeSequences()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com/a%c2%b1b".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/a%C2%B1b".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test3DecodingPercentEncodedOctetsOfUnreservedCharacters()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com/%7Eusername/".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/~username/".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test4RemovingTheDefaultPort()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com:80/bar.html".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/bar.html".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test5AddingTrailing()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com/alice".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/alice/?".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test6RemovingDotSegments()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com/../a/b/../c/./d.html".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/a/c/d.html".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test7RemovingDirectoryIndex1()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com/default.asp".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test7RemovingDirectoryIndex2()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com/default.asp?id=1".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/default.asp?id=1".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test7RemovingDirectoryIndex3()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com/a/index.html".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/a/".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test8RemovingTheFragment()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com/bar.html#section1".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/bar.html".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test9LimitingProtocols()
        {
            var url1 = "https://www.example.com/".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test10RemovingDuplicateSlashes()
        {
            var url1 = "http://www.example.com/foo//bar.html".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test11AddWww()
        {
            var url1 = "http://example.com/".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://www.example.com".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test12RemoveFeedburnerPart()
        {
            var url1 = "http://site.net/2013/02/firefox-19-released/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=firefox-19-released".NormalizeUrl();
            var url2 = "http://site.net/2013/02/firefox-19-released".NormalizeUrl();

            Assert.AreEqual(url1, url2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good code.. Just be careful, url normalization is not always a good thing, it depends on the context. For instance in your `Test5AddingTrailing` the two addresses can be considered different where it can point to two different things.

Answer (score 5):

You could probably use the `Uri` class to check individual parts of the urls, after converting each to the right format.

```
// Create the URI objects
// TODO: Use the right constructor overloads, 
// or do some processing beforehand to accomodate for the different scenarios
Uri uri1 = new Uri(url1);
Uri uri2 = new Uri(url2);

// There are overlaods for the constructor too
Uri uri3 = new Uri(url3, UriKind.Absolute);

// Check the correct properties
// TODO: Use the right properties...
if (uri1.AbsolutePath == uri2.AbsolutePath)
{
    // Urls match
}
```

Comment: This seems like it'll do what Made4Print wants. For further reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: yes, I am busy testing this:
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == new Uri(tempUrl, UriKind.Absolute).AbsolutePath)
which is very much the same.
However if I have ~/ in my sitemap, the provider is still adding ?Z=<id> to keep things unique and the Uri cant parse "~/?z=2" etc so as you say need to do some pre-checks.

Comment: Are there properties that don't contain the query string?  You may have to concatenate multiple properties to get a result that doesn't contain the query string.  Sorry I don't know too much more about the class.

Comment: @Made4Print: Do a string replace operation and swap out ~ with the proper beginning URL, which can be stored in a variable somewhere, and then create an object of the `Uri` class from that new URL. Alternatively (and this is probably the more proper way to do it), you can remove the ~ from the beginning of the URL, making it into a proper relative URL, then use the `Uri(<AbsoluteURI>, <RelativeURI>)` overload of the `Uri` class constructor, with `<AbsoluteURI>` being that aforementioned variable containing the absolute path. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DynamicSitemapASPNET2.aspx) can be of help to you?

> "...You want to see how to handle
>   identical Urls in the sitemap (which
>   is forbidden by the out-of-the-box
>   SiteMapProvider)..."

```
/// <summary>
/// SiteMap datasources cannot have duplicate Urls with the default provider.
/// This finds duplicate urls in your heirarchy and tricks the provider into treating
/// them correctly
/// </summary>
private void modifyDuplicateUrls()
{
StringCollection urls = new StringCollection();
string rowUrl = String.Empty;
uint duplicateCounter = 0;
string urlModifier = String.Empty;
foreach (DataTable dt in this.DataSource.Tables)
{
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
rowUrl = (string)dr["Url"];
if (urls.Contains(rowUrl))
{
duplicateCounter++;
if (rowUrl.Contains("?"))
{
urlModifier = "&instance=" + duplicateCounter.ToString();
}
else
{
urlModifier = "?instance=" + duplicateCounter.ToString();
}
dr["Url"] = rowUrl + urlModifier;
}
else
{
urls.Add(rowUrl);
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: I have implemented a custom SiteMapProvider, and have worked around this issue to suit the Standard ASP.NET Menu. In My case I am implementing a Custom Menu connected to the Sitemap Provider and do indeed want the abiility to highlight all paths to the same page. Thanks for th tip tho.

Comment: @Made4Print you're welcome - tell us what you've come up with that solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

What about seeing if Server.MapPath is equal for both urls?  (assuming this is an ASP.NET application, not ASP.NET MVC)

```
if (Server.MapPath(url1).ToLower() == Server.MapPath(url2).ToLower())
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This look feasable, but on the basis this is checking Menu URLs, ie could be a few, there might be a lot of overhead here? but will investigate.

Answer (score -2):

frankly, just load the URLs and compare their html contents?

Comment: The URLs need to be compared for each URL in a Menu/Navigation to check whether its the current page (to highlight the current page) Comparing content would be too much overhead.