# C# Equating URIs

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What is the standard way to determine that these 2 similar Uris are actually the same?

```
var a = new Uri("http://sample.com/sample/");
var b = new Uri("http://sample.com/sample");
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));

// False
```

What is the best way to determine that a == b?  I could compare the sub properties of the Uri object such as Host, LocalPath, etc, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Edit: Thanks everybody.  I basically just have to have the user enforce whether that are the same or not.

Comment: Those *aren't* the same. What makes you think they are? Taking this site as an example, compare `http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico` with `http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222610/check-if-2-urls-are-equal

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?    The URI's aren't the same and depending on a number of factors you will get very different results if you use these for browsing.

Comment: @Mark: you **should** perception the concept of uri! if you saw wordpress it have this: www.addr.com/index.php/2009/2/15/helloworld and it shows hello word post of the blog!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class overrides `Equals` and implements the `==` operator in order to determine equality.

The way to test if the two Uri instances are equivalent is:

```
if(a == b)
```

In your case, they are **not** equivalent. The directory terminator at the end of `a` has specific meaning, whereas `b` *might* be a directory or a file.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone commented - these Urls are not the same.

If you have some particular way of comparing Urls for **your** case - you need to write your own code to compare. Please try to use Uri/UriBuilder classes to parse Url into components instead of writing your own when comparing Urls. I.e. you may want to have your comparison to do case-insensitive compare of query strings.

If you want to say "urls are equal when they point to the same content" you have much more interesting problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement your own logic in which the two example above would be considered the same (I'm deliberately avoiding the term equal for obvious reasons) one solution would be to create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).  E.G.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool AreTheSame(this Uri left, Uri uri)
    {  
        //your implemention here
    }
}
```

then you can:

```
var a = new Uri("http://sample.com/sample/");
var b = new Uri("http://sample.com/sample");
Console.WriteLine(a.AreTheSame(b));
```

And you could use this method in your own [`IComparer<in T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) etc.

Comment: Exactly what OP wanted :)