# Checking to see if two URLs are equivalent

Tags: c#, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if 2 URLs are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222610/check-if-2-urls-are-equal)

Sometimes there are differences in ways that urls are typed but at the end they are equivalent. For example capital letters can be converted to lower case and a forward slash at the end or the url can be removed. As an example the two URLs are equivalent:

- www.myUrl.com
- http://www.myURL.com/

I am wondering what is the best way to make sure that two URLs are equivalent? what conditions are sufficient to make sure that two urls are pointing to the same document? (I am coding in C# so it would  be nice to see if there is a library that can do that too)

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, a forward slash at the end of a URL cannot always be removed and still have a URL that leads to the same location.

Comment: Theoretically urls shouldn't be case insensitive

Comment: @zerkms the base domain isn't case sensitive, but the rest of the url is.

Comment: @Austin Brunkhorst: I meant the left part of the url. But, does some specification requires web-server to handle `Host` header in case insensitive manner?

Comment: URL's may not be case insensitive but if you're trying to see that they take you to the same place when entered in a browser then FACEBOOK.com should equal facebook.com

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: "should" because... ? DNS is case insensitive, but I cannot find a proof that `Host` HTTP header is required to be case insensitive (by definition)

Comment: @zerkms because if type those two URL's in any modern browser I arrive at the same place. So it depends on what you consider to be equal. If you're trying to determine their equality from Internet Explorer users point of view then they are equivalent.

Comment: @Zerkms, check out the [RFC 3986 section Host](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) to get confirmation that host is case insensitive.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: "because if type those two URL's in any modern browser" -- well, it's not the case. Thanks to Alexei for pointing the standard for that. So in this case you should rely on documents, not on what you see at the moment. I'm sure you understand the difference. "If you're trying to determine their equality from Internet Explorer users point of view then they are equivalent." --- how would you know that? Have you tried to open all the sites over the internet and checked the host is case-insensitive? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Obviously not but I've tried enough to say with significant confidence that the browser is correcting the case prior to sending the request. Not to insult but if you think the average end user notices the difference between facebook.com and FACEBOOK.COM you don't know much about user experience. And that is the case, I just tested it with five sites (including little known sites like my favorite CS:S servers webpage) in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. Casing had no effect on where I landed in all cases.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: the question was about URL, not about some particular application (browser) behaviour. Even if browser does that - it doesn't mean it's required by a standard. And it doesn't mean that standard doesn't allow hostnames to be case sensitive.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, my original assertion was that when you use the browser casing is not a factor. My apologies if that was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the Uri library. For example you could compare by doing the following:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

For example:

```
Uri uri1 = new Uri(url1);
Uri uri2 = new Uri(url2);

// Check urls
if (uri1.AbsolutePath == uri2.AbsolutePath)
{
    // Urls match
}
```

You might also need to first look into doing URL Normalization:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization

Comment: Your code throws `UriFormatException`: “Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.”

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Uri class for checcking equivalent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

You have the `Host` proprety